# How to fetch images from the database

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am working in Laravel Framework, i have tried to fetch the image from the database. But it's not getting pulled properly from the DB, can anyone help me on this? 
Here is my code-

```
public function getAllPost()
{
    $posts = DB::table('posts')
            ->join('categories','posts.category_id','categories.id')
            ->select('posts.*','categories.name')
            ->get();

    return view('posts.all_posts', compact('posts'));
}

public function getIndividualPosts($id)
{
    $posts = DB::table('posts')->
             join('categories','posts.category_id','categories.id')
             ->select('posts.*','categories.name')
             ->where('posts.id', $id)->first();

    return view('posts.view_post', compact('posts'));
}
```

view.blade.php

```
        @foreach($posts as $post)

        <tr>
          <td>{{ $post-> id}}</td>
          <!--The name came from the categories table-->
          <td>{{ $post-> name}}</td>
          <td>{{ $post-> title}}</td>
          <td>{{ $post-> details}}</td>
          <td><img src="{{ URL::to($post->image)}}" style="height: 70px; width: 100px"></td>
          <td>
            <a href="{{ URL::to('posts.edit_post/'. $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-info ">Edit</a>
            <a href="{{ URL::to('posts.delete_post/'. $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Delete</a>
          <a href="{{ URL::to('posts.view_post/'. $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-success">View</a>
          </td>
        </tr>

        @endforeach

      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "_But it not pulled up properly_" What does that mean? Is the wrong image fetched? No image at all? Wrong path? Does the image exist? Is it readable?

Comment: What HTML does the PHP generate? What is the URL that gets put in the `src` attribute? Is it right? What is the value of `$post->image` itself?

Comment: hi @kerbholz yes it is readable, but when i run the code :
             DB::table('posts')
            ->join('categories','posts.category_id','categories.id')
            ->select('posts.*','categories.name')
            ->get();

basically this command is use for fetched all the values form the database right.
But it was came with all the values expect image and image was also broken, the image i stored into DB i saw its PATH into the database that was proper but somehow , when i execute the query the image not shown into the view file properly.

Comment: hi @Quentin yeah its the image value : $post->image and i used this for pulling the image value from the database , when i execute the query.